# What is the use of splitting dataset into training/test prior to cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, model-comparison

I've occasionally seen people advocate splitting the full dataset into training/test (typically a 70/30 or 80/20 split) **and** then running CV on the training set.

I don't fully understand the point of this, as I would expect that if you wanted to compare different models, or optimise parameters of a single model, then running CV on the entire dataset should be sufficient. The CV score would be an unbiased measure of how well that particular model or parameter generalises and so there's no need for an additional test set.

The only reason I can see for having an external test set is if you had selected one model out of 5 candidates by its CV score, and wanted to use it for a real application. Then the external test set would give an estimate of how it would perform on completely blind data, as the CV score is biased as you have selected the particular model from it.

Is that right? I'm essentially just wanting to know whether running CV on the entire dataset is sufficient for model comparison and parameter tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can split your dataset in a training and a validation set (also often called testing set as you mentioned). Then you perform

1) Internal validation: Cross-validation on the training set gives you the opportunity to make your model more robust (bootstrapping is even better for this).

2) External validation: The validation set allows you to validate externally your model so that you know how it will perform on unseen data.

External validation is a very important step if you want to be sure of the performance of your model therefore I would recommend to have a validation set (if you have enough data to do so).

Comment: Maybe one could add, that another hold out set could be used to optimize a model with respect to some parameters. Sometimes the validation set is used in this case